# SLES HA. How to run bashscript from cluster?

Tags: bash, high-availability, suse

I want to run simple unmount command before starting my "file-system" service on my node.
Is there any way to call bash script as cluster service?

Comment: This question better fits on superuser or server fault probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any script as a cluster service.  The script needs to be LSB compliant: i.e. needs to know start, stop, restart, status, etc.  I usually copy something simple from /etc/init.d and modify it for myself.

Put the script in /etc/ha.d/resource.d

Test it from command line 
    # sh /etc/ha.d/resource.d/start  (see if it unmounts)

Now if you haven't already, create resource group.  Add in all your resources into the same group.  Then add your new script in the resource group.  You can configure constraints so that all resources depend on your first application resource to run first.

That's about it.  You don't need to actually have anything configured for stop and status except "exit" since you just want your script to run once (to unmount)

Here is a script that *might* work in /etc/ha.d/resource.d

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# description: testapp auto start-stop script.
#

. /etc/rc.status

case "$1" in
  start)
      umount [filesystem]
      ;;
  stop)
      ;;
  reload*|restart*|force-reload*)
      ;;
  status)
      ;;
  *)
      echo "options: start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|status"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
exit
```

Hope that helps

I have an outline of my steps for building clusters plus an ebook here: 
http://geekswing.com/geek/building-a-two-node-sles11-sp2-linux-cluster-on-vmware/